# Access to resources (images) inside jars/classpath

Tags: java

Hey I have a panel that contains a label that i have to change it's icon everythime i click on a button ( there are 2 buttons here activate and disactivate ) .and these 2 images that i want to set as icons are in my ressources under a backage called "imgs". 
Example : imgs/img_x.png so who to change that icon ? cause i always get a null pointer exception.
i need that in java not in Android
Thanks

```
Icon c=new ImageIcon(getClass().getResource("src/imgs/img_not_activated.png"));
        img_etat_pharmacie.setIcon(c);
```

Comment: I doubt the path of the resource starts with src.

Comment: i don't want it in android but in Java ( J2SE )

Comment: Could you add your project structure.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
Icon c = new ImageIcon(getClass().getClassLoader().getResource("imgs/img_not_activated.png"));
img_etat_pharmacie.setIcon(c);
```

Comment: of course, "imgs/img_not_activated.png" must be in the classpath

Comment: Icon c=new ImageIcon(getClass().getClassLoader().getResource("src/imgs/img_not_activated.png"));
        img_etat_pharmacie_activ.setIcon(c);
i'm still having the same prob :(

Answer (score 1):

Images don't go in the src folder.
Save them under res/drawable;  Then access them like:

```
    Drawable dr = getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.arrow);
```

Please see the resource part of this [tutorial](http://www.vogella.com/tutorials/Android/article.html#resources_overview).

Comment: i need it java not in Android :)

Comment: ok still looking for a bit more info on this though, i saw the android tag...before the edit, is this an android app? something on android?  Reply up top so everyone who reads your question will see.