# How do I access a file in this hierarchy?

Tags: java, eclipse

I have this file hierarchy:

> Java Resources
>
> > `src`
> >
> > > `model`
> > >
> > > > `Class.java`
>
> Web Content
>
> > `datos.txt`

I need to access from **Class.java** to **datos.txt**. I tried using **C:\Users\Tomi\Documents\Eclipse\ProyectoWeb\WebContent\datos.txt**
but when I use this application in another computer, it doesn't work. How can I modify that direction?

Comment: It seems you are working on a web project. If so you must use relative path

Comment: Does the other computer have access to your "local" computer? Are you on a network (so you could create a "shared folder")?  Are you trying to deliver your project on a "web server", then there is another way to do that.

Answer (score 1):

Use relative paths. For example if your application is at `C:\Users\Tomi\Documents\Eclipse\ProyectoWeb` then use `WebContent\datos.txt` as the path.

Then even if you move your application it will still look for the folder WebContent in the folder the application is running in then datos.txt within that.

Answer (score 0):

For a more portable way you could embed it in the classpath an access to it via classloader, see [Access to resources (images) inside jars/classpath](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22185225/access-to-image-from-ressources-in-java/22185553#22185553) for example or [Unable to load picture from resource](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22045718/unable-to-load-picture-from-resource/22046065#22046065)